# Akka: How to take messages from a BlockingQueue in a non-blocking way?

Tags: scala, akka, blocking, nonblocking

I have an event stream and would like to send new messages from that stream to various actors in an actor system. The stream provides a blocking getNext() call. It also provides an event listener that takes a BlockingQueue.

I think I want to publish messages to Akka's Event Bus. This would involve publishing to the Akka event bus in the event listener's event handler method.

But the consumer event queue is blocking (it's a BlockingQueue). How can I set up this blocking call in a way that won't cause performance problems or otherwise violate Akka's guidelines not to block inside actors?

Comment: If it's a stream who "takes a `BlockingQueue`" than you could implement `BlockingQueue[E]` with `add` implemented as `def add(E e) = actorRouter ! e`.

Comment: You don't need to be an actor to publish to the event stream, so why not publish to the event stream from outside of the actor system?  Setup a dedicated thread to read from the blocking queue and then call `system.eventStream.publish(someMsg)`.  This will allow you to inject events into the actor system w/o causing problems with the dispatcher in that system.